# Прослушать переход между страницами

Tags: jquery-mobile, html5

Так как все страницы находятся в одном теге `body`, то после покидания страницы с аудио, плеер продолжает петь. 
Как можно выловить то, что пользователь покинул страницу и остановить аудио?

Comment: документацию читать не пробовали? тут лень не двигает прогресс.

Comment: Не нашел в докементации события назад. Искал тут http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: pagechange, pagebeforechange, pagebeforehide. пробуйте, все возможно.